# Creating minimal release-ready header file for C++ class

Tags: c++, osx-lion, static-libraries, header-files

I made a C++ class that I've put in its own static library.

I also decided to create a minimal header file that would allow other people to see the `public:` part of the class. So I basically took the original header file (which is rather long, contains the `private:` and `public:` parts of the class, etc.), and stripped out everything but the `public:` part (which is short, only the constructor/destructor and one public function).

To test things out I've created a dummy project that would use the library. The thing is, whenever I use the minimal header file in that project, it crashes with messages like:

```
test(44349) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdab2c242e8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

But whenever I include the original header file, it works fine.

What could be the problem? It compiles fine (no warnings even with `-Wall`) using both the minimal and the original header files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work and violates the *one-definition rule*: Every class must have precisely one definition, and each translation unit must see the exact same definition, or otherwise your program is ill-formed, and worse, no diagnostic is required.

You might be better served with the PIMPL idiom, by which you split your class into two parts, and you do not need to expose the implementation component:

```
// Ship this:

class FooImpl;

class Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<FooImpl> impl;
public:
    Foo();
    void do_magic();
};

// Don't ship this:

class FooImpl { void magic(); };
void FooImpl::magic() { /* secret code */ }

Foo::Foo() : impl(new FooImpl) { }
void Foo::do_magic() { impl->magic(); }
```

See Herb Sutter's [GotW #101](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/) for a nice general-purpose framework for PIMPL classes.

Comment: This seems promising, thanks. So there's no other (simpler) way? I have to use two classes? Do all C++ libraries do this?

Comment: @houbysoft: I think most C++ libraries just don't bother hiding things. Ultimately, there is no *conceptual* penalty for allowing your client to see the non-public parts of your classes. In any event, you must never violate the ODR.

Comment: I see... I'm not really looking to hide things, but some of the `private` functions of my class have custom types for arguments that need other headers, etc., so it would've been much simpler to just strip those away for the release version of the header file...

Comment: @houbysoft: PIMPL definitely helps you decouple compilation dependencies, and many large projects use it as an essential discipline to keep compilation times manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the private/protected part of a class from the interface: the compiler using the interface must know of the (private/protected) member variables and virtual functions, otherwise it would have a wrong idea of the class instances and the virtual table.